# Installation of Sphere v2.7

Tags: speech-recognition

I tried installing the NIST Sphere downloaded from [here](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/mig/tools.cfm) but I am facing the following errors.

```html
< bin >>
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/bin'
gcc -m32  -I/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/include -L/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/lib -g -g -DNARCH_LINUX bias.c  -lm -lsphereCombinedLibs -o bias
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/lib/libsphereCombinedLibs.a(shorten.o): In function `shorten':
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/shorten.c:499: undefined reference to `log'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/shorten.c:554: undefined reference to `floor'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/shorten.c:558: undefined reference to `floor'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/shorten.c:559: undefined reference to `exp'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/shorten.c:560: undefined reference to `pow'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/shorten.c:561: undefined reference to `log'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/shorten.c:561: undefined reference to `floor'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/shorten.c:876: undefined reference to `log'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/lib/libsphereCombinedLibs.a(lpc.o): In function `wav2lpc':
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/lpc.c:59: undefined reference to `log'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/lpc.c:93: undefined reference to `log'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/lib/libsphereCombinedLibs.a(poly.o): In function `wav2poly':
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/poly.c:59: undefined reference to `log'
/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/lib/sp/poly.c:62: undefined reference to `log'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bias] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/src/bin'
```

Can anyone help me about it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late, but in case if anyone else is facing the same problem -

The errors are due to math library incorrectly linked. The -lm flag must be given after the -lsphereCombinedLibs :

```
gcc -m32  -I/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/include -L/home/nagaraju/Documents/Speech/nist/lib -g -g -DNARCH_LINUX bias.c  -lsphereCombinedLibs -lm -o bias
```

To do so, go to lib/makes/make_spg.txt file, and replace the LLIBS definition to

```
LLIBS   = -l$(COMBINEDLIB) -lm
```